# In Azure App Deploy how to generate JWT token?

Tags: azure, jwt

I have followed the given step and created a Azure sample app. I was able to deploy and test using PowerShell from Azure BDC.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/big-data-cluster-consume-apps?view=sql-server-ver15#generate-a-jwt-access-token

In Azure docs, there are no details on what is JWT token and how to generate one. Please provide steps/ref.

Comment: That's weird, because the document you mention has a detailed instruction how to get one.

Comment: @emix Followed that instructions giving me a swagger file but no TOKEN :(

Comment: The Swagger file is just a documentation. You are supposed to actually hit the API, did you ever open the swagger editor? It's well explained in the document.

Comment: @emix - when I hit the API I get only - "401 Authorization Required" I never got any user login as mentioned in the doc, so I am under the assumption I might be ready some old docs.

Comment: Sigh: 401 means you didn't pass the JWT token most probably. Find a method which returns a JWT token, this one you can call being unauthorized.

Comment: Do you want to generate your token using power Shell?

Comment: I don't know anything about swagger stuff and so I am not understanding anything.

Comment: Swagger is a documentation and Testing the documentation i.e testing the methods as per the documentation. You wud need to supply a JWT Token and input into the respective header fields as shown in the Swagger docs and you wud hopefully get a 200 response. 401 means it Not Authorized, cos you did not provide a JWT or invalid JWT.

Comment: Try Auth0 for JWT Token. The format is "Bearer some_valid_token_very_long_alphanumeric_string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swagger is a documentation file for API Endpoints. Like Readme.md for a GitHub project. Using online [swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) one gets to view & test API Endpoints.

In the above case, an app is deployed to Azure Big Data Cluster using "azdata" tool and the goal is to trigger this app using REST API.

1. **Step1.1**: To get JWT (JSON Web Token) of your BDC cluster. Go to `https://<ip_addr>/api/v1/swagger.json` using your "azdata" credentials.

   **Step1.2**: This will return you a Swagger JSON file. Using the Above editor, you can check the above the editor and look to TOKEN API in this swagger.

   Once you submit this Token Post request with "azdata" login creds, it returns a JSON file.
2. **Step2.1**: Using "azdata", describe your application to get application swagger file.

   **Step2.2**: Using "swagger.editor" do post/run with application swagger file. To authorize use the token collected from step1.

   Here you would be doing a post request to `https://<ip_addr>/api/app/<your_app_name>/v1/run`